# What is an efficient way to check if an HTML input is right or wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, onclick

I'm creating a quiz with `<input type="text">` and `<input type="number">`.

I find that making a bunch of `if` / `else` statements is extremely inefficient, due to the bulk of the JavaScript code.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!--Question 1-->
<label for="a">A cow says =</label>
<input type="text" id="a"/>

<!--Question 2-->
<label for="a">1 + 1 =</label>
<input type="number" id="b"/>

<button onclick="checkQuiz()">Check Quiz</button>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
var a = document.getElementById("a")
var b = document.getElementById("b")

function checkQuiz() {

// Question 2
   if (a.value == "moo") {
      console.log("correct")
   }
   else {
      console.log("wrong")
   }

// Question 2
   if (b.value == "2") {
      console.log("correct")
   }
   else {
      console.log("wrong")
   }
}
```

I'm down for some Jquery code answers, just I'm also don't know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of correct answers, and look up the index of the question input in the answer array to compare the appropriate value.

```js
// tweak the selector as needed
// you'll probably want something more precise
const questionInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const correctAnswers = ['moo', '2'];
function checkQuiz() {
  questionInputs.forEach((input, i) => {
    console.log(`Question ${i + 1}: ${input.value === correctAnswers[i] ? 'Correct' : 'Wrong'}`);
  });
}
```

```html
<!--Question 1-->
<label for="a">A cow says =</label>
<input type="text" id="a"/>

<!--Question 2-->
<label for="a">1 + 1 =</label>
<input type="number" id="b"/>

<button onclick="checkQuiz()">Check Quiz</button>
```

Comment: The next step would be to have an array of question+answer and generate the inputs dynamically from that.